# How to assign an array to a variable in an Ansible-Playbook

Tags: ansible

In a playbook I got the following code:

```
---
- hosts: db
  vars:
    postgresql_ext_install_contrib: yes
    postgresql_pg_hba_passwd_hosts: ['10.129.181.241/32']
...
```

I would like to replace the value of `postgresql_pg_hba_passwd_hosts` with **all of my webservers private ips**. I understand I can get the values like [this](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-loop-over-a-list-of-hosts-in-a-group-inside-of-a-template) in a **template**:

```
{% for host in groups['web'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth1']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

What is the simplest/easiest way to **assign the result of this loop to a variable in a playbook**? Or is there a better way to collect this information in the first place? Should I put this loop in a template?

Additional challenge: I'd have to add `/32` to every entry.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can assign a list to variable by [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/set_fact_module.html) and ansible [filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins).

Put custom filter plugin to **filter_plugins** directory like this:

```
(ansible top directory)
site.yml
hosts
filter_plugins/
    to_group_vars.py
```

**to_group_vars.py** convert hostvars into list that selected by group.

```
from ansible import errors, runner
import json

def to_group_vars(host_vars, groups, target = 'all'):
    if type(host_vars) != runner.HostVars:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError("|failed expects a HostVars")

    if type(groups) != dict:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError("|failed expects a Dictionary")

    data = []
    for host in groups[target]:
        data.append(host_vars[host])
    return data

class FilterModule (object):
    def filters(self):
        return {"to_group_vars": to_group_vars}
```

Use like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      web_ips: "{{hostvars|to_group_vars(groups, 'web')|map(attribute='ansible_eth0.ipv4.address')|list }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "web ip is {{item}}/32"
    with_items: web_ips
```

Comment: The example works very well. Thank you! Now the only step that I'm missing is how can I assign the value of `web_ips` to `postgresql_pg_hba_passwd_hosts` like in the question?

Comment: In Ansible 2.0, HostVars can be found in ansible.vars.hostvars.

Comment: Note: `from ansible import runner` has been changed in Ansible >v2.x See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14018

Comment: **For Ansible 2.0**, replace the `from ansible import runner` with `from ansible.vars.hostvars import HostVars`. Update the type check accordingly. This is beautiful. I wish I could upvote this again. You've saved me hours of work!

Answer (score 15):

in playbook:

```
vars:
     - arrayname:
        - name: itemname
          value1: itemvalue1
          value2: itemvalue2
        - name: otheritem
          value1: itemvalue3
          value2: itemvalue4
```

in template: (example is of type ini file, with sections, keys and values):

```
{% for item in arrayname %}
[{{ item.name }}]
key1 = {{ item.value1 }}
key2 = {{ item.value2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

This should render the template as:

```
[itemname]
key1 = itemvalue1
key2 = itemvalue2
[otheritem]
key1 = itemvalue3
key2 = itemvalue4
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the example I needed to see. I want to write some config files and I need to use 2-3 variable for the template file.

Answer (score 6):

Variables can be represented as standard YAML structures so you can assign a list value to a key like this:

```
---
- hosts: db
  vars:
    postgresql_ext_install_contrib: yes
    postgresql_pg_hba_passwd_hosts:
      - '10.129.181.241/32'
      - '1.2.3.0/8'
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete solution, i.e. how do I get the values dynamically from the collected facts?

Comment: KISS, this works just fine and can be used as such `{%for ntpserver in ntpservers %} server {{ ntpserver }} iburst {% endfor %}`

Comment: or if you need only the first element of the array, `{{ ntpservers[0] }}`

Comment: Ha-ha, thank you so much, Tima, I was looking specifically for `postgresql_pg_hba_passwd_hosts`. It's a miracle that you're using the same variable!

Answer (score 4):

You can use jinja2 filters:

```
{{ groups['nodes']|map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth1','ipv4', 'address']) |list }}
```

will return a list of ip addresses. i.e.

```
---
- hosts: db
  vars:
    postgresql_ext_install_contrib: yes
    postgresql_pg_hba_passwd_hosts: {{ groups['nodes']|map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth1','ipv4', 'address']) |list }}
...
```

Does not include the challange (appending `/32`). But it should also be possible somehow with jinja2 filters.

Reqiures ansible version >= 2.1

Answer (score 0):

To add '/32' to the address, you can use the Ansible ipaddr filter ([converting to CIDR notation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#getting-information-about-hosts-and-networks)).

```
{{ ip_addresses|ipaddr('host') }}
```