# How to override a subset of ansibles array variables?

Tags: arrays, yaml, ansible

How should one go about overriding only a portion of an array in Ansible?
That is, I have a set of default in my role (./roles/delta/default/main.yml) like so:

```
---
delta:
  name: "delta-snapshot"
  roles: []
```

and then I have the a faily simple ./vars/delta.yml with the following:

```
---
delta:
  roles:
    - name: admin
      rights: "0x3FF"
    - name: test
      rights: "0x20F"
    - name: "simple"
      rights: "0x005"
```

the problem here is that I have to provide the `delta.name` variable since `delta` gets completely replaced with the new version which is not what I want. I've tried defining the list like `delta.roles: ...` and `delta[roles]: ...` but then it is treated like a totally different variable name and the empty list is being used instead.

Answer (score 2):

My experience has been, avoid using same variable name twice in ansible, because of the way variables are handled by it. This implicitly means avoid overriding/changing values of variables (instead create a new variable with a different name). Authors explicitly refuse to answer any questions related to scope/precedence etc.

That said, for your case, simplest solution would be to create a new variable like:

```
---
delta:
  name: "{{delta.name}}"
  roles:
    - name: admin
      rights: "0x3FF"
    # ...
```

Or if you have recursion problems due to scope then change the name :-)

```
---
overridden_delta:
  name: "{{delta.name}}"
  roles:
    - name: admin
      rights: "0x3FF"
    # ...
```

If you want to retain the name then cheat by making it a fact:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      dict1: {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
      }
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="before = {{dict1}}"
  - set_fact: {
      dict1: {
       key1: "{{dict1.key1}}",
       key2: 'overriden value2'
      }
     }
  - debug: msg="after = {{dict1}}"
```

Or go with the silver bullet (a little less readable IMO) custom filters like this: [How to assign an array to a variable in an Ansible-Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798382/how-to-assign-an-array-to-a-variable-in-an-ansible-playbook)