# Usage of loop for comma separated variable in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a script for multiple time using a loop.

The way I want it is

```yaml
Script: /{{home}}/{{appUser}}/bin/trade_data_dnld.ksh {{ date }} {{ trade_id }}
```

Now my requirement is to run the same script for a hundred trade IDs and its not really possible to run the playbook hundred times.

I am looking for an option where I can create a variable called `trade_id` (free text) and pass the `trade_id` in a comma separated format.

The playbook should pick those trade IDs in the list and run it in loop for each one.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29216525/948762

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it this way

```yaml
- shell: /{{home}}/{{appUser}}/bin/trade_data_dnld.ksh {{ date }} {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ trade_id.split(',') }}"
```

And pass the variable to the playbook using `-e trade_id="dsdsd,sdsdsd,dsds"` in your `ansible-playbook` command.
`split` will create a list of values and the shell task will iterate over this list and will run each time with the corresponding value.

Comment: You might also be interested in [with_sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence), depending on the values, but I make no assumption that they will be so conveniently consistent. ;)