# Prompt variable to input values in list format (with_item/loop)

Tags: linux, ansible

```yaml
- name: testplay  
  hosts: localhost  
  gather_facts: false  
  vars_prompt:  
    - name: register_name  
      prompt: "Enter your register name in a listformat to pick one by one"  
      private: no  
  
    - name: node_list  
      prompt: "Enter your register names in list like  
 same,charles,william,george"
      private: no
      with_items: "{{ register_name }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "display all {{ register_names }} here"
  
    - name: write register names to a file one below the other  
      shell: echo '{{ item }}' >> file.txt  
      with_items: "{{ register_name }}"
```

I want to enter the values in list for prompt module to pick one by one, not sure how the loop works here, please suggest (with_item/loop i tried and not working)

```
# ansible-playbook test.yml  
Enter register_no in a listformat to pick one by one: same,charles,william,george
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of loop for comma separated variable - Ansible Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096205/usage-of-loop-for-comma-separated-variable-ansible-playbook)

Comment: I rolled back you edit since it makes your question totally different from the initial one. Ask a new one. Before you do that, i **very strongly** suggest your read [ask], you extensively use the research bar on top of this site, and you take some time to get used to the post editor interface to format your code correctly for your next post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vars_prompt` accept text. There's no way to enter a list from scratch. But it's easy to implement using `split` (adding `trim` for security). In a nutshell, the following `prompt_demo.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: registered_names_prompt
      prompt: Please enter names. Separate multiple elements with coma
      private: no

  vars:
    registered_names: "{{ registered_names_prompt.split(',') | map('trim') }}"


  tasks:
    - name: Debug our var in a loop
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ registered_names }}"
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook prompt_demo.yml 
Please enter names. Separate multiple elements with coma: toto,pipo ,bingo, bla , bli, blo

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Debug our var in a loop] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=toto) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "toto"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=pipo) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "pipo"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=bingo) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "bingo"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=bla) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "bla"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=bli) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "bli"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=blo) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "blo"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I tried above playbook, but when i want to pass the values captured in registered_names:  with include role, the loop is not working., it takes only last value

Comment: Please [edit your question](/posts/75696115/edit) and provide a [mre]. While you're at it you probably want to take the [tour] then [head to help section](/help) to get a better understanding of how SO works and what is expected from its users.